# OutofMemory Error while getting ImageList From ActiveAndroid Database

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-image, activeandroid

I am creating a app which capture images and stores into Internal storage as well as local storage in ActiveAndroid. In starting i have faced many issues regarding OutofMemory error. But I have cured that error by handling and compressing image after go through [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html). But now when I am getting list from ActiveAndroid app crashes in some device and gives outofMemory error.
Below is my code and error Response.

**In Background Service I am getting List like:**

```
 List<ImageUploadModel> imagesList = ImageUploadModel.getUnUploadedImageListonintimation(uploadImageModel.getIntimationId());
```

**In active android my Query is**

```
public static List<ImageUploadModel> getUnUploadedImageListonintimation(String IntimationId) {
    return new Select().from(ImageUploadModel.class).where("intimationId=?", IntimationId).where("isImageDetailsUpload=?", false).execute();
}
```

**I am getting error**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 422472 byte allocation with 343696 free bytes and 335KB until OOM
   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(CursorWindow.java)
   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:66)
   at com.activeandroid.Model.loadFromCursor(Unknown Source)
   at com.activeandroid.util.SQLiteUtils.processCursor(Unknown Source)
   at com.activeandroid.util.SQLiteUtils.rawQuery(Unknown Source)
   at com.activeandroid.query.From.execute(Unknown Source)
   at com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.Model.ImageUploadModel.getUnUploadedImageListonintimation(Unknown Source)
   at com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.Service.UploadImageService$3.getResponce(Unknown Source)
   at com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.Volley.VollyRequests$1.onResponse(Unknown Source)
   at com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.Volley.VollyRequests$1.onResponse(Unknown Source)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(Unknown Source)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.onFinish(Unknown Source)
   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6343)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

Comment: why downvote, Please Mention....

Comment: *with 343696 free bytes and **335KB until OOM*** ... it means that you are doing some memory rape before this ... also it seems like your column contains string with 422472 length ... that's all what I can tell with this question

Comment: will u please elaborate...

Comment: No, question is asked in the way that's is all that we can say

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your memory management more efficently.

My advice would be:

- Take a look at this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Vx1OvzrLa3Y0R0X1BZbUpicGc/view) to get an understanding of how memory is limited across different Android versions / screen sizes (note: it only shows it until Marshmallow)
- Don't load your full sized image, load just a thumbnail of it.
- Use the local storage of the phone instead of the database (won't really help with memory management but its more convenient :3)
- Let [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) help you :)
- In the list where you display the images, only load the ones that are currently needed (and only the thumbnails)

Comment: I am not setting image from here, I just want to get the list from the local database and upload it to the server. so for this, I have not to use Glide

Comment: Then don't read all of them at once. Just read one, upload it and repeat :)